# Query doesn't work if I move hardcoded quotation marks

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

## Brief history

I have a JavaScript object which stores query templates with `$nameParam` so that it can be replaced with `string.replace()`. Issue is that until now I needed `$nameParam` to be in quotation marks and now I need to get rid of them. Depending on when they are added, the query either works or not. I have observed some interesting behaviour:

## Method which replaces string

This method basically calls database and gets records. You can see the longest line - it's responsible for replacing `$nameParam` with the provided parameter.

```
function setupEndpoint(app) {
  app.get('/neo4jdb/:queryType',
    async (req, res) => {
      const session = driver.session();
      res.on('finish', () => session.close());
      try {
        const response = await session.run(queryTemplates[req.params.queryType],
          { nameParam: req.query.name });
        let statement = response.summary.query.text.replace('$nameParam', `"${response.summary.query.parameters.nameParam}"`);
        statement = statement.replace('RETURN', '\nRETURN');
        console.info(`Neo4j statement: ${statement}`);
        res.send({ rawItems: response.records, statement });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting Neo4j', configs);
        console.error(err);
        res.send({ error: 'Error connecting Neo4j' });
      }
    });
}
```

## Working example

Query template

```
const queryTemplates = {
  getShipsForCompany: `MATCH (A:Company) -[RELATIONSHIP]-> (B:Ship) MATCH (B:Ship)-[RD]-()
  WHERE A.name=$nameParam RETURN B as Ship, A as Company, type(RELATIONSHIP) as R, count(RD) as degree limit 50`
};
```

Replacement

```
response.summary.query.text.replace('$nameParam', `"${response.summary.query.parameters.nameParam}"`);
```

Produced output

```
Neo4j statement: MATCH (A:Company) -[RELATIONSHIP]-> (B:Ship) MATCH (B:Ship)-[RD]-() WHERE A.name="TRINITY HOUSE"
RETURN B as Ship, A as Company, type(RELATIONSHIP) as R, count(RD) as degree limit 50
```

## Not-working example

Query template

```
const queryTemplates = {
  getShipsForCompany: `MATCH (A:Company) -[RELATIONSHIP]-> (B:Ship) MATCH (B:Ship)-[RD]-()
  WHERE A.name="$nameParam" RETURN B as Ship, A as Company, type(RELATIONSHIP) as R, count(RD) as degree limit 50`
};
```

Replacement

```
response.summary.query.text.replace('$nameParam', `${response.summary.query.parameters.nameParam}`);
```

Produced output

```
Neo4j statement: MATCH (A:Company) -[RELATIONSHIP]-> (B:Ship) MATCH (B:Ship)-[RD]-() WHERE A.name="TRINITY HOUSE"
RETURN B as Ship, A as Company, type(RELATIONSHIP) as R, count(RD) as degree limit 50
```

## Summary

Both produced output queries are the same. Why first one returns results and second one is empty? (2nd one copied to DB engine works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j cypher syntax is below.

```
WHERE A.name=$nameParam
```

It should NOT have double quotes on the parameter name. Thus, the 2nd example is syntax error during runtime.